# Problems using JBox2D DebugDraw with Slick2d

Tags: java, box2d, slick2d, jbox2d

I am writting a little Game where I use Slick2D and JBox2D. Now to my problem:
I try to use an DebugDraw for the engine. But every version i find on the internet doesnt work. They throw the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
  at org.jbox2d.pooling.normal.MutableStack.<clinit>(MutableStack.java:35)
  at org.jbox2d.pooling.normal.DefaultWorldPool.<init>(DefaultWorldPool.java:66)
  at org.jbox2d.dynamics.World.<init>(World.java:122)
  at Windows.GameState.init(GameState.java:36)
  at org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame.init(StateBasedGame.java:171)
  at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.setup(AppGameContainer.java:393)
  at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:317)
  at HTLin2D.main(HTLin2D.java:38)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
  ... 8 more
```

If needed I can post the DebugDraw version I am using. Used JBox2D version is 2.1.2.3.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030065/classnotfoundexception-org-slf4j-loggerfactory

Comment: Oh sorry didnt found that, ty