# slf4j issues in stanford core nlp and openccg

Tags: java, linux, nlp, classpath, stanford-nlp

I'm following the `ccgbank-README` in openCCG when I have the following issue (just part of the log file):

```
ner-tag-text:
     [echo] NER tagging into file ./data/novel/two-sents.dir/nertext
     [echo] Models: ./stanford-nlp/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz , ./stanford-nlp/classifiers/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz, ./stanford-nlp/classifiers/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz
     [java] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:194)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.run(Java.java:771)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:221)
```

which says that there is a `NoClassDefFoundError` with `org/slf4j/LoggerFactory`. I searched the Internet and I found many people had the same problem. So I followed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030065/classnotfoundexception-org-slf4j-loggerfactory) by adding

```
slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar
slf4j-simple-1.7.2.jar
```

to my classpath. After that, I have the classpath as follows:

```
zhao@zhao-ubuntu:~$ echo $CLASSPATH
/home/zhao/slf4j-simple-1.7.21.jar:/home/zhao/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar
```

However, this doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Could you post the full command you're using to run CoreNLP? My guess is that you're overriding the classpath explicitly on the command line, and so the $CLASSPATH variable is not getting picked up.

Comment: did you add the jars to your buildpath?

Comment: Oh. Thanks. Problem solved by using an old version of CoreNLP. Version 1.3.4 may be better for OpenCCG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by using an version 1.3.4 of CoreNLP.